# Intro stats, one-way repeated measures ANOVA finding standard deviation from missing data?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I'm trying to do a one-way repeated measures ANOVA, but I'm missing some data in the question (I'm not looking for the answer, just a hint on what I'm missing here..). The data in question is:

Paint types:

1 data: {10,6.2,7.6}

2 data: {11.3, 9.2, 9.9}

3 data: {10.3, 9.2, 9.8}

4 data: {11.8, ?, ?}

The overall Standard deviation is 1.657.

Notice in the fourth paint type there is missing data. I have the SStr = 8.67, although I'm not sure how to find the SSE since from what I know I need the standard deviations for this.

There was a previous question with this same data but there were two factors and I was able to do the two-way ANOVA fine with the info given. Any tips for this one-way ANOVA?

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer! Didn't know $SST = (N-1)S^2$. Was able to figure everything out from there. :-)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157036)

Comment: @kjetil In this case, it appears that the OP has managed to answer their own question. Though obviously this answer would be more helpful to future readers if it mentioned (though not necessarily explaining in detail) how one can go from the given formula to a solution to the problem.